# Existence of an uncountable well-ordered set with a certain property

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to find $Y$ an uncountable well-ordered set with the property that for any element in $Y$ there are at most countably many elements less than it.

My attempt: I'm assuming the existence of $X$ an uncountable well-ordered set by the well-ordering theorem. My idea was to take $\mathcal{A}:= \{ X' \subseteq X: X\setminus X' \textrm{ is at most countable} \}$ and then $Y:= \{ \min X': X' \in \mathcal{A} \}$. This would automatically make $Y$ well-ordered and satisfy the additional property. However, I can't prove that this $Y$ is uncountable.

Comment: So you're looking for the first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ordinals but now that you mentioned it a quick search shows me the construction I needed:
https://www.math.fsu.edu/~bellenot/class/su08/found/other/omega-one.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an uncountable well-order $(X,<)$ and define $C= \{x \in X\mid \{y \in X\mid y < x\} \text{ uncountable }\}$. If this set happens to be empty then $X$ itself is as required. If not, let $c_0 = \min C \in X$ which exists as $(X,<)$ is a well-order and let $Y = \{x \in C\mid x < c_0\}$ in the inherited order and $Y$ is then clearly as required, by minimality of $c_0$.

Comment: If Y is defined as $\{x\in X \mid x < c_0\}$, it is easy to justify Y is uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming axiom of choice, consider the cardinal $\aleph_1$ that is also an ordinal and is therefore well ordered.

Any element of $Y \in \aleph_1$ is an ordinal. The cardinality of $Y$ is at most countable by definition of the cardinal $\aleph_1$.

Comment: You don't need choice. If you look at the proof of Hartogs' theorem, the order type of $\omega_1$ can be described in terms of classes of well-orders on subsets of $\Bbb N$.